# databinding for simpleform in ui5

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I am using a grid including a sinpleform to view data from a JSON model. The JSON model is named to mysettings. `oView.setModel(this.models.mysettings, 'mysettings');`

The grid looks like the following

```
<mvc:View
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns="sap.m">

<Page>
<l:Grid
    defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
    width="auto">
    <l:content>
        <f:SimpleForm
            minWidth="1024"
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="false"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="3"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="4"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1"
            content="{mysettings>/settings/Group/0/Parameters}">
            <f:content>
                <Label text="{mysettings>OneOfTheKeys}" />
                <Input value="{mysettings>TheCorrespondingValue}" />
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </l:content>
</l:Grid>
</Page>
</mvc:View>
```

The JSON model is

```
{
    "settings": {
        "Group": [
            {
                "Parameters": 
                {
                    "key1": "value1",
                    "key2": "value2",
                    "key3": "value3",
                          ...,
                          ...
                },
                "Name": "TheName"
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

How is it possible to use a databindig to get the view of a simpleform like in [the linked example at the end](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/b8/7b4b705c144423a2fec1628b85a486/content.htm?original_fqdn=help.sap-ag.de&frameset=/en/5a/6ffde8380041ffa11ed5c10431b4aa/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=449) with the given JSON model? The number of the key-value-pairs is not given.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `SimpleForm` because of the special way it treats `Label` and other controls; you may try with standard `sap.ui.layout.Form` and aggregate on `FormElement` though

Comment: @Qualiture the key actually here is to not bind aggregation and have every binded value be an absolute path. this is how it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need an array when you bind a multiple aggregation. And you actually bind a plain object instead.

Either change your model (if possible) to something like

```
{
    "settings": {
        "Group": [
            {
                "Parameters": 
                [
                    { key:"key1", value: "value1"},
                    { key:"key2", value: "value2"},
                    { key:"key3", value: "value3"},
                          ...,
                          ...
                ],
                "Name": "TheName"
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

Or use a formatter function to transform your object into an array

```
content="{ parts: [ 'mysettings>/settings/Group/0/Parameters' ], formatter :'.myFunctionToArray' }"
```

then your bindings to

```
<f:content>
    <Label text="{mysettings>key}" />
    <Input value="{mysettings>value}" />
</f:content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate your aggregation binding and instead bind every value with the full address (an absolute path + relative path together):

```html
<form:SimpleForm class="formHiddenTitle" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanM="12" labelSpanL="12" labelSpanXL="12" columnsM="4" columnsL="4">
  <core:Title/>
  <m:Label class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Work Order Number" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Work Order Number}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Category" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Category}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Travel Time" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Travel Time}" />

  <core:Title/>
  <m:Label class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Call Date" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Call Date}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Service" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Service}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Work Time" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Work Time}" />

  <core:Title/>
  <m:Label class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Invoice Number" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Invoice Number}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Issues Found" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Issues Found}" />

  <core:Title/>
  <m:Label class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Invoice Date" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Invoice Date}" />
  <m:Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" design="Bold" text="Technician" />
  <m:Text text="{/WorkOrderSet/Technician}" />
</form:SimpleForm>
```

This is how you will be able to both have groupings using `Title`/`Toolbar` and be able to bind every value. Once you do this, binding `Label`'s should be no issue